C: handle pointer to subset of array as small array
I have a problem where I need to handle small slices of a big array of doubles.
Is there a way to define a pointer which lets me handle it as a small array?
Given:
double bigarr[10000] = {0.0};
// doing something to fill the array

double *smallarr[10] = &bigarr[297];

int i;
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
    *smallarr[i] += 15.0;
}

This example should result in adding 15.0 to the elements from bigarr[297]..bigarr[306] (but this is just an example. I want to do something more complicated)
What's the easiest way to achieve this?

smallarr should just be a pointer, i.e. double *.

double *smallarr = &bigarr[297];. It allows you to address starting at index 297 in the bit array, but it doesn't have a 10-element limit.

Then you just use smallarr[i], you don't need to dereference it. This is the normal pointer<->array relationship in C.

// doing something to fill the array you realize the array is already filled (initialized) with 10000 zeroes, right?

A pointer to an array element is just that. It does not encompass the index of the element it points to, or how many elements remain til the end of the array. You need to manage that separately. So, just a pointer to the start of the region of interest and a separate variable to hold the length of interest - as long as you remain within the bounds of the actual array. If you want, you could bundle these 2 items into a struct.

It's even a bit simpler than @Barmar says: double *smallarr = bigarr + 297; makes a pointer to bigarr[297] and then you can use smallarr[i] to access bigarr[297 + i]. Bonus: i can be negative, too, to access elements prior to  bigarr[297].

Ok and thank you all! I'll try the answer from CiaPan. At the moment I am a bit confused, because I got an error message. Maybe I changed something when copying.
@pmg: yes I know,. Maybe should have written "..with interesting data" I tried to reduce complexity from the original code and I always start with initializing to avoid gaps


Is there a way to define a pointer which lets me handle it as a small array?

A plain double * will serve just fine:
double *smallarr = &bigarr[297];

or
double *smallarr = bigarr + 297;

You can then use smallarr much like you would bigarr, with smallarr[0] equivalent to bigarr[297].
On the other hand, your original

double *smallarr[10] = &bigarr[297];


is an array of pointers, not an array of double nor a pointer to an array.  You can define a pointer to an array:
double (*smallarr_ptr)[10] = (double (*)[10]) &bigarr[297];

... but the syntax for using that is not the same as the syntax for using bigarr.  And you don't gain much from encoding the sub-array length into the pointer type, especially if it's constant.

I wonder whether double (*smallarr_ptr)[10] =  &bigarr[297]; is defined behavior because there is no array of 10 elements there. There are (ideally) 10 elements, but that's a different matter. Syntactically it would also need a cast in C++ (C is probably more lenient, but it should produce a warning with a sufficiently high warning level): double (*smallarr_ptr)[10] = (double (*)[10])&bigarr[297];.

Thanks, @Peter-ReinstateMonica. It needs a cast in C, too, (added) though some compilers will accept it without.

It is a subtler question whether there actually is an array of ten elements there, and also whether there needs to be one to avoid violating the strict aliasing rule.  There is not a declared array, to be sure, but C defines arrays like so: "An array type describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects with a particular member object type" (C23 6.2.5/25), and there is indeed such a thing there.  Moreover, no such array is ever itself accessed (only members), as a whole-array access cannot even be expressed in C.

Oh but it can be expressed and accessed, exactly by and through the construct here (taking its address). It is unidiomatic and rare, but it exists. E.g., -- not telling you anything new here -- one can pass a pointer to such an array to a function and thus retain the length/size information (of a type and hence an object of that type) etc. It's just not very valuable without templates, which is why it is rare. (As an aside, K&R (R from above) are probably wondering what the world has come to and why I'm not doing something useful ;-) ).

@Peter-ReinstateMonica, taking an object's address is not accessing the object, as the C spec defines that term.  And nothing you can do with a pointer to an array produces an access to the array itself, at least as far as the strict aliasing rule cares, any more than anything you can do with an lvalue representing the array itself does.

Thank you! That did it. For my needs double *smallarr = bigarr + 297; is sufficient. Before i was keeping the 297 as base in the index and that is nerving.

You can use a pointer directly to point to the desired section of the array.Like for eg instead of double *smallarr[10] = &bigarr[297]; you can just do double *smallarr = &bigarr[297]; and then use a loop to process (as in smallarr[i]).
